# Autofit Column Width in C#-generated Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to Autofit the columns and rows in an Excel sheet that I make by exporting data from a SQL Server database, using C#. I've done a bit of research, and the solutions I've found don't seem to have any affect.

```
//This code produces the correct Excel File with the expected content
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
for (int i = 1; i < myDataTable.Rows.Count + 2; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j < myDataTable.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
   {
      if (i == 1)
      {
         ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = myColumnCollection[j - 1].ToString();
      }
      else
         ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = myDataTable.Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
   }
}
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(Application.StartupPath + "\\test.xlsx");
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

//This code is where I tried to do the Autofit work
Excel.Worksheet ws = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange; 
//ws.Columns.ClearFormats();
//ws.Rows.ClearFormats();
//range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
//range.EntireRow.AutoFit();
ws.Columns.AutoFit();
ws.Rows.AutoFit();

ExcelApp.Quit();
```

I've tried a few methods near the end. I think I understand the difference between `Range.Columns.Autofit()` and `Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit()`, and have tried using `Worksheet.Columns.ClearFormat()` before AND after getting the `UsedRange`. None of these have affected my file at all, as far as I can tell.

What do I need to do in order to have the columns and rows autofitted to their content?

Comment: this should be working as far as I can tell

Comment: I've also tried using `ws.Columns["A:G"].AutoFit();`, and that didn't have an affect either.

Comment: can you call ws.AutoFit(); ?

Comment: ok stupid question but may be worth checking, but is `Worksheets[1]` the correct worksheet? theres not actually 2 worksheets there and you are referring to the wrong one? im just spitballing

Comment: ws.Columns["A:Z"].AutoFit(); try something like that

Comment: @Derek, nope, that doesn't work. And I tried the second suggestion after posting the question.

Comment: @psoshmo, There's only the one worksheet. Good idea though, I hadn't checked.

Comment: Your not saving the workbook after you apply the autofit, shouldnt yoube saving teh changes?

Comment: @psoshmo, good question.  The way I would do this: capture return value of Workbooks.Add and used later (instead of using ActiveWorkbook).  I would choose the Worksheet using the captured workbook.  I would modify cells in the captured worksheet (instead of using the App.Cells).  I would autofit the captured worksheet.

Comment: @Derek, that was it. That was all I had to do. Doh. (I'm new to actually participating on Stack Overflow, so if I need to do something to make sure you get credit for the answer, let me know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks goes to Derek for pointing out the obvious. I needed to save the Workbook after I was done modifying it. I just had to move my `Autofit()` stuff above the save.

```
 Excel.Worksheet ws = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
        ws.Columns.AutoFit();
        ws.Rows.AutoFit();
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(Application.StartupPath + "\\HaulerInfo.xlsx");
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
```